# modal popup is calling ready function nuber of times

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog

Am using this in Laravel.

On one view am calling modal pop up and in this pop up ajax call is getting called.
when I close this modal, and again click on modal pop up, it is calling that ajax call 2 time.
again close and open, it calls 3 times !

Not getting the exact issue. Am not using any loop there.

View from where calling the modal pop up:

```
   <a title="Add New Travel Request under this request" data-toggle="modal" onclick="LoadModals('TravelRequest','<?=$request->TP_tr_request_id?>')" ><img src="<?=$assetsBase?>/img/domestic_travel_3.svg" style="width:35px"></a>
```

Modal div :

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="SubTravelRequestModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="SubTravelRequestLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
   <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:70%">
      <div class="load_modal"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and the function which is getting called on click of above image

```
    function LoadModals(typeOfModal,TR_id)
    {
        if(typeOfModal=="TravelRequest")
        {
            $.post( '/travel/tr/subTravelRequest'  ,{id:TR_id}, function( data ) {
                $('#SubTravelRequestModal').modal();
                $('#SubTravelRequestModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                    $('#SubTravelRequestModal .load_modal').html(data);
                });
                $('#SubTravelRequestModal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function(){
                    $('#SubTravelRequestModal .modal-body').data('');
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

This laravel route calls the view which is nothing but 
     
      
       my view content here

in this modal, at end i have

```
    $(document).one('ready', function () {
        alert("in this ")
        onefunction("this is calling number of times ")
    });
```

whenever this is getting opened, onefunction is calling number of times.

Can somebody explain me the what is wrong work here ?